# Can't connect to database: Host 'XX.XX.XX.XX' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Tags: mysql, perl

I am trying to connect my database from my Perl program on linux, it is actually a work project. I need to fetch some values which are present in different tables.

The code I am using for the connection is below :

```
my $dbType = "mysql";
my $database = "trustid";
my $host="XXX.XX.X.XX";
my $dsn="";
my $userid="";
my $password="";

if($dbType eq "mysql") {

    $dsn      = "DBI:$dbType:database=$database;host=$host:port=3306";
    $userid   = "user_id";
    $password = 'password';

} else {

    $dbType   = "postgres";
    $userid   = "postgres";
    $password = "postgres";
    $dsn      = "DBI:$dbType:database=$database;host=$host,port=XXXX";

}

my $dbcon = DBI->connect($dsn, $userid, $password) or 
        die "Can't connect to database: $DBI::errstr\n";

print "connected to the database\n";
```

When I am trying to execute it by ./aa.pl it is showing the following error:

```
root@tc-lab-02:/home/abcdefgi/Ajay_POC/XL_Parsing# ./aa.pl
DBI connect('database=abcdefgi;host=XXX.XX.X.XX:port=XXXX','trusavc_sa',...) failed: Host 'YYY.YY.Y.YY' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server at ./aa.pl line 40.
Can't connect to database: Host 'YYY.YY.Y.YY' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

I have changed the user to the root, still I am unable to make the connections.

Comment: Look for explanation on how to allow access to mysql db from outside hosts. By default, mysql can be connected only from localhost (127.0.0.1). The configuration file of mysql includes a variable for  this setting.

Comment: @nazim when i am trying to do this from local host the output is similar, the change i am doing is storing $Host variable to localhost

Comment: Changing $host will not be effective. Connection IP is important for mysql and this needs to be allowed in the mysql config file. xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is not equal to yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy .... trying to connect to x from y is not allowed until you change the setting

Comment: @nazim Ok, but when i changed the my $host="localhost"; it is now not giving me that error but it started giving --DBI connect('database=trustid;host=localhost:port=3306','trustid_sa',...) failed: Unknown database 'trustid' at ./aa.pl line 40.
Can't connect to database: Unknown database 'trustid'  . why it is now?

Comment: Do you have a database named "trustid"? Change it to "test" to see if that helps. Remember, tables and databases are two different things.

Comment: _when i changed the my $host="localhost";_  When you do that it tries to connect to a MySQL instance on your local machine, which obviously does not have a database _trustid_

Comment: @barrycater when i have changed my db name to test, it is working fine and connection is established but why it is happening, it should do the same if i have the db called trustid on the same VM!

Comment: @clamp i am doing this on VM's of my office project it  is having that db I must say because the main project code also uses $host= localhost in the source code .

Answer (score 2):

You need to connect to `localhost` (instead of `XXX.XX.X.XX`) if the database server is local (i.e. on the same machine as the Perl program).

If the database is remote, you'll need to create a tunnel to that machine's `localhost`, or you'll need to adjust the MySQL server's configuration to accept connections from your machine.

---

When communicating over the internet, one doesn't communicate with a machine so much as with a network adapter on that machine. A machine might have multiple network adapters, each with its own network address. These logical network adapters correspond to physical network adapters (e.g. ethernet, wifi, etc) and to virtual network adapters (e.g. an interface between a host system and a VM hosted on that system).

All internet-capable systems have a special virtual adapter known as the loopback adapter. This is the one assigned the IP address to which `localhost` resolves (usually 127.0.0.1 [IPv4] and/or ::1 [IPv6]).

What's special about this adapter is that it can only be used to communicate with itself. This means two things:

1. When you communicate with `localhost`, you also communicate from `localhost`.
2. When you communicate to something other from `localhost`, you also from something other than `localhost`.

For security reasons, MySQL only authorizes connections from this interface by default. This ensures that you only expose your database to programs running on your system.

But because of the "rules" listed above, it means you must connect to `localhost` to access your database, not some other interface such as a your ethernet or wifi interface.

For example, consider a system with these interfaces:

```
$ ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.24.241.85  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 172.24.255.255
        inet6 fe80::215:5dff:feef:f494  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:15:5d:ef:f4:94  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 620620  bytes 187701194 (187.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 179  bytes 12626 (12.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

(This is from Linux. On Windows, you can use `ipconfig`, but newer version don't actually show the loopback adapter.)

If this machine runs MySQL with its default configuration, it will listen to all interfaces for connections. However, it will only authorize connection coming from 127.0.0.1 and from ::1.

This can be achieved by connecting to 127.0.0.1 or ::1, but it can't be achieved by connecting to 172.24.241.85 or fe80::215:5dff:feef:f494. The latter two would reach the MySQL server (since it listens to all interfaces on the machine), but it would reject the connection with the error message you obtained ("Host '*ADDRESS*' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server").